# Smarty if - chaining variables in if statement

Tags: php, html, smarty

How is it this possible?

This is not a problem:

```
{if $date.today.start eq $filter.selected} selected="selected" {/if}
```

But I wonder how is this possible? (Chaining variables in if statement)

```
{if {$date.today.start}|{$date.today.end} eq $filter.selected} selected="selected" {/if}
```

This throws me an syntax error.

So how is it possible that I can combine

`$date.today.start` with a "pipe" and another variable `$date.today.end`:

```
{$date.today.start}|{$date.today.end}
```

in an IF Statement?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself.

"cat" can solve this problem:

```
{if $date.today.start|cat:'|'|cat:$date.today.end eq $filter.selected} selected="selected" {/if}
```